# Android's ListView randomly without separator

Tags: android, listview, divider

I'm removing the divider png's from my app, and replacing it with a simple black line.
I thought that android put a simple default divider (1px black) between items, but I have it only in some ListViews...  why?
If I try to insert an `android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"` and/or `android:dividerHeight="1dp"`, I don't see any divider. Again, why?

Comment: I faced the same issue but when i set divider programmatically and solved it.u can try like :`list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
  list.setDividerHeight(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 1px as dividerHeight, and not 1dp. 1dp will mean 0.75px in 120dpi devices - which is rounded off to 0px.

Comment: thanks! and do you know why  android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end" doesn't work?